# C: Recursive function - Binary search

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I'm trying to build a recursive function which returns the address within a sorted array by comparing to the middle value and proceeding based on relative size. Should the value not be in the array, it is supposed to simply print NULL. Now the first part of the function works, however whenever a null is supposed to happen I get a segmentation fault. The code looks as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h> 

int *BinSearchRec(int arr[], int size, int n){
  if(n==arr[size/2]){
    return &arr[size/2];
  } 

  else if(n>arr[size/2]) {
    return(BinSearchRec(arr, size+size/2, n));
  }

  else if(n<arr[size/2]) {
    return(BinSearchRec(arr, size-size/2, n));
  }

  else{
    return NULL;                    
  }
 }

 main(){
    int numb[]={2,7,8,9};

 if((int)(BinSearchRec(numb, 4, 22)-numb)>=0)   {
    printf("Position: %d \n", (int)(BinSearchRec(numb, 4, 22)-numb)+1);
    }

     else{
       printf("NULL \n");
     }

  }
```

Comment: Your function returns and `int *` and you treat it like an `int`. Also `NULL == 0` => `NULL >= 0`.

Comment: this seems wrong, you are adding `size` to `size/2` which is larger then `size` and you reach out of your array eventaully

Answer (score 6):

Your recursive calls are wrong. In the first case you claim that the size of the array is 50% *larger* than originally, and you're passing the pointer wrong (you should pass the second "half" of the array).

In both cases, the size of the "array" is always half of what the function received. And in the second case, you need to pass a pointer to the second half of the array.

Something like

```
else if(n>arr[size/2]) {
  return(BinSearchRec(arr + sizeof/2, size/2, n));
}

else if(n<arr[size/2]) {
  return(BinSearchRec(arr, size/2, n));
}
```

---

You're also treating the returned value from the function wrong. It's not a value, it's a *pointer* to the value, you need to treat it as such. And it's okay to subtract one pointer from another (related) pointer, it's called *pointer arithmetics*.

Comment: There's a typo in your code. It should be `return(BinSearchRec(arr + size/2, size/2, n));`.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what others have said about not dividing the array properly and not using the return value correctly, your function is missing a termination condition.

In your code, the las `else` will never be reached, because the three preceding conditions cover all possibilities: `n` is either smaller than, equal to or greater than `arr[size/2]`.

You should test whether your subarray actually has elements before you access and compare them. Here's a revision of your code:

```
int *BinSearchRec(int arr[], int size, int n)
{
    int m = size/2;

    if (size == 0) return NULL;
    if (n > arr[m]) return BinSearchRec(arr + m + 1, size - m - 1, n);
    if (n < arr[m]) return BinSearchRec(arr, m, n);

    return &arr[m];
}
```

And here's an example `main` that shows how you make use of the pointer that was returned. If the pointer is `NULL`, the number is not in the array and you cannot dereference the pointer.

```
int main()
{
    int numb[] = {2, 7, 8, 9};
    int n;

    for (n = 0; n < 15; n++) {
        int *p = BinSearchRec(numb, 4, n);

        if (p) {
            printf("%d: @%d\n", n, (int) (p - numb));
        } else {
            printf("%d: NULL\n", n);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a single `size`, it is easier to reason with 2 indexes (`left` and `right`) delimiting the sub-array you are exploring. 
Modifying your code according to this approach gives:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h>

int *BinSearchRec(int arr[], int left, int right, int n){
  if (left > right) 
    return NULL;

  int mid = (left + right) / 2;

  if(n == arr[mid])
    return &arr[mid];

  if(n > arr[mid])
    return BinSearchRec(arr, mid + 1, right, n);
  else
    return BinSearchRec(arr, left, mid - 1, n);
 }


int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
  int numb[] = {2,7,8,9};
  int *p = BinSearchRec(numb, 0, 3, 22);

  if (p) {
    printf("Position: %d \n", (int) (p - numb + 1));
  } else {
    printf("NULL \n");
  }
  return 0;
}
```